# api-instagram---For a long time to get this error please guide

Tags: php, api, instagram

For a long time to get this error please guide

```
<?php
$address = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$address);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
"grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=123456
&client_secret=12346
&redirect_uri=http://site.ir?GO=instagram
&code=1234556
");
 $send = curl_exec($c); 
?>
```

Error code

> error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid grant_type"

please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Instagram changed the way how you obtain valid access token for given Instagram account. Please follow instructions on their [official documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).
You will not be able to obtain access token the way you are trying.